# iOS action sheet

Tags: iphone, ios, operating-system, uiactionsheet

I'm using UIActionSheet in one of my applications and I have a question . When the action sheet comes to front , everything else goes in background and I cannot interact anymore with my buttons or other objects in my view until I dismiss the action sheet . Is there a way to disable this feature ? I mean , if I have the action sheet displayed , can I still be able to use what goes in background ? If there is a way , I would really appreciate if you could show me how to do it.

Comment: You can add the views that you want to interact with to the passthroughViews of the UIPopoverController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to access the Background controls, If the `UIActionSheet` or `UIAlertView` comes to the front.

Answer (score 1):

The action sheet is supposed to be modal. All user input will be captured by the action sheet until it is dismissed. So all the background controls cannot be interacted with by the user until it is gone.